# What is the meaning of "Ich gehe davon aus"?

Tags: meaning

What does the expression

> "Ich gehe davon aus"

mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"*von etwas ausgehen*" = "*etwas voraussetzen*"

English translations: "assume", "premise", "presume"

A German example:

> Ich gehe davon aus, dass Sie diesen Artikel gelesen haben.

Same meaning:

> Ich setze voraus, dass Sie diesen Artikel gelesen haben.

English translation:

> I assume/premise that you did read this article.

Answer (score 6):

You could translate it as:

> I'm assuming that...

[Here](http://www.dict.cc/?s=davon+ausgehen) is the dict.cc translation page and [here](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=davon+ausgehen) the leo.org page of:

> davon ausgehen

So it's basically an assumption one thinks is true or it's not really knowing, but you figure.

Answer (score 4):

"Pusten Sie hier nicht so herum", sagte die Kerze zu dem Kellner, "ich gehe davon aus!". "Ich gehe davon aus" erwiderte der kaltherzige Kellner...

Comment: +1 for answering the question without answering the question yet answering some unasked questions at the same time, answering the real question indirectly.